# animating in 3 steps one after the other ios

Tags: ios, animation

I have 3 cards. at first all cards move to the right, then after 1 sec card2 would appear on the left side of the view, and then after some more second card2 moves to the right. I implemented this using the following code. when the view loads I have the following code,

```
counter = 0;
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(performAnimationToRight) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

here is the implementation of the performAnimationToRightMethod

```
-(void)performAnimationToRight
{
if (counter == 0) {

    CGAffineTransform transformToLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(388,0);

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Move1" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];

    card0.transform = transformToLeft;
    card1.transform = transformToLeft;
    card2.transform = transformToLeft;

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}else if(counter == 50){

    card2.frame = CGRectMake(-300,card2.frame.origin.y, card2.frame.size.width, card2.frame.size.height);

}else if(counter == 200){

    timer = nil;
    counter = 0;
    CGAffineTransform transformToLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-300,0);

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"Move2" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:2];

    card2.transform = transformToLeft;

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}

counter++;
}
```

the problem is that on the last action card2 instead of moving to the right moves to the left, and that's wether or not I use,

```
    CGAffineTransform transformToLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-300,0);
```

or

```
    CGAffineTransform transformToLeft = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(+300,0);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two comments:

First, you are moving your card2 to the left at `counter == 50` by setting it's frame origin to be (probably) left of your starting position.

Second, this would be easier to implement using a `CAKeyframeAnimation`. You wouldn't have to manage your `NSTimer` and the `counter` mechanism.